# Timezone is wrong in database

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, zoneinfo

I have made a date with the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function in phpmyadmin. And the output value of the hours is wrong by 1hour. I have tried changing it in mysql using the 
`SET TIME_ZONE = '+01:00';`

However it will still submit the date with 1 hour earlier. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're touching a complex topic.

When a column of a table has the `TIMESTAMP` data type, all values are stored in UTC *after* translating from your current `time_zone` setting to UTC. When you retrieve values from those columns they are translated back to your current `time_zone`.  This is handy because you can present datestamps to users globally in their own local time by treating the `time_zone` as a user preference.

When a column has the `DATETIME` data type, the translations *do not occur*.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);


SET time_zone = 'UTC';
INSERT INTO t1 (ts, dt) VALUES (NOW(), NOW());
SET time_zone = 'Europe/Paris';
INSERT INTO t1 (ts, dt) VALUES (NOW(), NOW());


SET time_zone = 'UTC';
SELECT  * FROM t1;    /* notice differences presentation of ts columns, ds stay the same */
SET time_zone = 'Europe/Paris';
SELECT  * FROM t1;    /* again */
SET time_zone = 'America/Halifax';
SELECT  * FROM t1;    /* again */
```

**Pro tip:** If you use named time zones `Europe/Paris` you'll automatically get the benefit of the daylight time rules for the locale you chose. The rules, known as the [zoneinfo database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), are maintained by [IANA](https://www.iana.org/). Many Linux distributions include changes to the zoneinfo database in their regular updates.